Returning records based on 2 conditions in ACCESS
I just started learning Access and QRY/SQL. I need some help on creating a query that pulls all the sales to be paid based on the following 2 conditions:
1- Sales status does not equal to Reversal Reasons status. If the status is one of the Reversal Statuses, the Paid date should = Rev Pd Date
2- Sales status does not equal with Unpaid Hold Reasons. If the status is one of the Unpaid Hold Reasons Statuses, the paid date should = Unpd Hd Date
This is what the QRY looks like:
SELECT [BLUE New Sales TBL].AppID, [BLUE New Sales TBL].Business, 
[BLUE New Sales TBL].[Sales Rep], [BLUE New Sales TBL].Created, [BLUE New Sales TBL].Status, 
IIf([Reversal Reasons]![ID] Is Not Null,"YES") AS [Reversal?], 
IIf([Unpaid Hold Reasons]![ID] Is Not Null,"YES") AS [Unpd Hd?], 
[BLUE New Sales TBL].[Last Update], [BLUE New Sales TBL].[Date Pd], 
[BLUE New Sales TBL].[Date Rev], [BLUE New Sales TBL].[Hold Rev], 
[BLUE New Sales TBL].[Date Mgr Pd], [BLUE New Sales TBL].[Date Mgr Rev]
FROM [Unpaid Hold Reasons] AS [Unpaid Hold Reasons_1] 
RIGHT JOIN ([BLUE New Sales TBL] LEFT JOIN [Reversal Reasons] 
ON [BLUE New Sales TBL].Status = [Reversal Reasons].Status) 
ON [Unpaid Hold Reasons_1].Status = [BLUE New Sales TBL].Status
WHERE ((([BLUE New Sales TBL].[Date Pd])=[Forms]![Form2]![Pay Date]))
ORDER BY [BLUE New Sales TBL].[Sales Rep], [BLUE New Sales TBL].Created;

This is what the Datasheet looks like and "Incomplete - Payment Issue" is the Unpaid Hold Reason.

This is the Design View of the QRY

As you can see, I have the Pd Date show under the Paid column, which is what I wanted to see all the Sales being paid, and it does not include any of the sales with reversal reasons which is good ("Decline - Closed as Lead" is a paid status, not a reversal reason). But the "Incomplete - Payment Issue" (Unpaid Hold Reason) should not be there. The paid date for the Unpaid Hold Reasons should be in the "Date Unpd Hd" column and why does the column "Unpd Hd?" have "YES" on all the of paid statuses? I am so confused. What did I do wrong?
Thank you so much for your help!
I tried LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN but it didn't work.
Edit: I thought by copying how the existing condition was done for the new  condition, the QRY should work but it does not.
Below are the original QRY and datasheet:

Why did you bother with an alias name for [Unpaid Hold Reasons]? You have identified autonumber fields as keys but you are linking on Status text fields. Relationships look odd and I don't understand them. Tables should link on key/foreign key fields. Neither JOIN includes primary key fields.

What is purpose of Renewal and Unpaid tables?

I am still very new with Access. I don't understand much about autonumber fields and how the relationship works. My boss, whom created the original QRY, retired and now I find myself trying to mimic his QRY to add an additional clause because the Sales Team wants to exclude a new sale status, which is the reason I created Unpaid Hold Reasons. They just don't want to pay the commission on that status for those sales.

I added the original QRY and datasheet to the post so you can see (hopefully it will show on the post). I was just trying to mirror how the existing one was done.

I don't know your business model so "don't want to pay the commission on that status for those sales" is Greek to me. However, the JOINs you show in query don't make sense. Understanding table relationships is basic to successful db design/management - you need to get a grip on that fast. A solid week with an introductory book on Access wouldn't hurt.

Thank you! I think it finally clicked last night. I attempted to redo the query and it worked. Thank you for your help!

If you found a solution, you are encouraged to answer your own question in space below. Please do so to resolve this post and please answer with enough helpful information for future readers.
